# Handle Union of List in C# with duplicates

Tags: c#, list, merge, union, duplicates

I am trying to understand how to handle union or merge of two lists that can have duplicates.
For example, List1 has { A, B, C} and List2 has { B, C, D }.
I tried to use the Union operation and got a new list with values (A, B, C, D}. However, I need the B & C values from the second list, not first one.
Is there a way to specify the union method, which duplicate value to use.

The code I am using now is

```
var newList = List1.Union<Object>(List2).ToList();
```

Thanks for any help.
Javid

Comment: How do you know they are from one list instead of the other?

Comment: Yes, I did try reversing the list by doing a union with List2.Union(List1). However, this changes the order and I end with a list like { B, C, D, A}. What I am trying to achieve is, my List 1 order needs to be preserved and should be replaced with duplicates from List2.
Sorry, I should have made this point clear before.

Comment: Am I the only one completely lost at what you are trying to achieve here? When you have duplicates, how could you tell which is which?

Answer (score 7):

Union is logically a set operation. Concat is what you're looking for.

```
List1.Concat(List2)
```

Comment: `Concat` results in `B` and `C` from both `List1` and `List2` in the result instead of just `B` and `C` from `List2`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just do:

```
var newList = List2.Union<Object>(List1).ToList();
```

.. as reversing them will probably give you the ones you need?

**EDIT:**

That apparently doesn't work. Sorry, I didn't test it, it was just a first reaction to the problem.

How about, using the reversed notation above, but then calling List.Sort() to get them back in the order you want? It assumes that you have a property to order by, but you could even artifically create one if someone doesn't come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var newList = List2.Union<Object>(List1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could look at [`Join`ing](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx) your lists instead. After that operation you'd have the "join" objects for each duplicate to inspect...

Comment: Hi Rob, Do you have any sample code. I am quite new to Linq and trying to understand as much as I could.
Thanks

Comment: sorry, there was a link hiding on my post: http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx